# Batch Job with JPA running extremely slow

Tags: java, performance, jpa, transactions, batch-processing

I'm facing a performance issue with my batch job written with JPA (Using OpenJPA) which running as plain Java Application. I'm trying to insert huge list of objects, like more than 10 million records. I know this design is not correct. But I will get this amount of data all of sudden and no way to split up the entire job.

I have split up the list with sub lists of size 100 000 each. And I call JPA transaction method for each of this sub list. In each such transaction I flush the list when it reaches 2000. As per my understanding, for a 1 million records it make 100 transactional call.

Once job started, I could see that 6 million records inserted in around 15-20 minutes taking an average time of only one minute for 300 000. But after it reaches 6-6.5 million, job is running extremely slow, like 10 thousand in 4-6 minutes, feeling like stopped. But It keeps on running and no heap memory shortage also.

Could anyone tell what mistake in my code. I tried with different chunk sizes (25K, 50K, 100K) for sub list. I 'm not getting any idea on what causing this slowness after middle of the Job. Should I clear the EM after each transaction? I have increased the connection pool size also.

Here is my code:

```
    @Stateless()
    @LocalBean
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
    public class BatchService{

    @EJB 
    private PersonService personService;

    public void run(List<Person> personList) {
            int totalEventSize = personList.size();
            int quotient = totalEventSize / 100000;
            int modulo = totalEventSize % 100000;
            int totalIterations = quotient + (modulo != 0 ? 1 : 0);
            int startCount = 0;
            int endCount = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= totalIterations; i++) {
                if (i == totalIterations) {
                    endCount = totalEventSize;
                } else {
                    endCount = startCount + 100000;
                }
                List<Person> subList = personList.subList(startCount, endCount);
                personService.create(subList);
                startCount = endCount;
            }

        }

    }

    @Stateless
    @LocalBean
    public class PersonService implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private PersonDLService personDLService;

    public void create(List<Person> list) {
            try {
                personDLService.createPerson(list);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}


    @Stateless
    @LocalBean
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY)
    public class PersonDLService implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @PersistenceContext(unitName = Constants.PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME)
        private transient EntityManager entityManager;

        public void createPerson(List<Person> personObj) {
            for (int i = 0; i < personObj.size(); i++) {
                entityManager.persist(personObj.get(i));
                if (i % 2000 == 0) {
                    entityManager.flush();
                    entityManager.clear();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("***************** COMMITED ****************" + personObj.size());
        }

    }
```

Comment: don't you have an BatchInsert available into entityManager ? Or maybe an SQL BatchInsert with SQL request and no Hibernate EntityManager.

Comment: Im using OpenJPA which does not have batchInsert implementation I believe. With my above code everything working fine till 60% of the processing.

Comment: Hard to say. Me personally I would simplify this code and just have sublists of 2000 entities rather than having to manually flush and clear every 2000 iterations. That keeps the transaction size down too. But I am going to make a guess that the problem is actually in the database, expensive index updating for example.

Comment: @Gimby If I make more such small sub lists, will it create large number of transactions which eventually make performance overhead by high resource consumption like CPU time ? BTW if it is the problem with DB as you suspect, how can I confirm it and what is the solution pleas

Comment: Please don't use non-English words like "lakh" here, and especially using something like "6L" will definitely confuse people.

Answer (score 0):

Too much data is very often an issue when using JPA in batch jobs. And 10 millions rows to insert is a lot.

First, I would use a better api when having more than 100000 rows: batch jdbc.

For example using batch jdbc:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY)
public class PersonService implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@PersistenceContext(unitName = Constants.PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME)
private transient EntityManager entityManager;

public void doIt() {
    // get a jdbc connection from the entityManager (unwrap(Connection.class) is openjpa specific)
    // or you may as well get a jdbc connection from a jdbc DataSource
    try (Connection connection = entityManager.unwrap(Connection.class)) {
        // if Postgresql or Oracle DB, you may need to add a nextval for a sequence in the sql
        String sql = "insert into person (name) values (?)";
        try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            int i = 0;
            for (Person person : personList) {
                i++;
                statement.setString(1, person.getName());
                statement.addBatch();
                if (i == 1000) {
                    statement.executeBatch();
                    i = 0;
                }
            }
            if (i > 0) {
                statement.executeBatch();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

If that's not enough, you may try to add `connection.commit()` each million rows.